# Tell sqlldr control file to load missing values as NULL

Tags: csv, sql-loader

I have a CSV file. How can I tell the sqlldr control file to load missing values as NULL. (ie the table schema allows NULL for certain column)

Example of CSV

```
1,Name1
2,Name2
3,
4,Name3
```

Could you help me to edit my control file here so that a line 3 , the missing value is inserted as NULL in my table

Table

```
Create table test
( id Number(2), name Varchar(10), primary key (id) );
```

Control file

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '{path}\CSVfile.txt'
INSERT INTO test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(id CHAR,
 name CHAR
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using **TRAILING NULLCOLS** will do the job BUT it has to be for "blanks" at the end of the record line.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE {path}\Your_File
INSERT INTO TABLE Your_Table
TRAILING NULLCOLS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
(
 ... your fields
)
```

Comment: Confusingly the DDL for a external table accepts '`MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL`' - however that does not seem to be supported in a SQLLDR Control File.

Comment: @YoYo I wish I could tell you somthing about it but I cant. I have never used that option with external tables. Try AskTom I bet they can answer better you inquiry here or start a new thread here.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to hint to SQL*Loader that there might be nulls in your data.

2 ways to give that hint to SQL*Loader.

- Use **TRAILING NULLCOLS** option.

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '{path}\CSVfile.txt'
INSERT INTO test<br>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(id CHAR,
 name CHAR
)
```

- Recreate your CSV files with enclosed fields and then use **OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'** which lets SQL*Loader clearly see the nulls in your data (nothing between quotes) that looks like `"abcd",""`

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '{path}\CSVfile.txt'
INSERT INTO test<br>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(id CHAR,
 name CHAR
)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `NVL(:home_points,0)` will substitue `NULLs` encountered in `home_points` by `0`. This is not what I was trying to do. I wanted undefined values to be recorded as `NULL` i.e. the column `home_points` is nullable. `0` is NOT a `NULL` value

Answer (score 2):

I believe all you should have to do is this:

```
name  CHAR(10) NULLIF(name=BLANKS)
```

Comment: nope it's not that. What you gave will just ignore the record and treat it as a recodr to be discarded. I found that TRAILLING NULLCOLS will do the trick.

Comment: D'oh, of course.  I have that in my control files also.